# using Python, Flask and Ajax, how can I parse a response from an ajax call and print as HTML?

Tags: python, ajax, flask, twilio

I want to make a call to Twilio api, via Ajax, and get sms logs and then print the results as HTML. I cannot parse the response, from the ajax call, correctly.

The python code is:

```
@application.route("/custom_log", methods=['POST'])
def customlog():
    to_number = request.values.get('to_number', None)
    user_id = session.query(User.id).filter(User.validation == request.cookies.get("validation")).scalar()
    sub_account_sid = session.query(Credential.twilio_id).filter(Credential.user_id == user_id).scalar()
    sub_account_auth_token = session.query(Credential.twilio_token).filter(Credential.user_id == user_id).scalar()
    client = TwilioRestClient(sub_account_sid, sub_account_auth_token) 
    msgs = client.messages.list(to=to_number) 
    for m in msgs:  
        print m.status
    return msgs
```

The ajax code is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#custom_log_btn" ).click(function() {
    alert('script')
        var to_number = $('#to_number').val();
        //var date_from = $('#datepicker_from').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' }).val();
        //var date_to = $('#datepicker_to').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' }).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/custom_log',
            data: { 'to_number': to_number }, 
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(msgs) {
                alert(msgs)
                var html = '<table class="table table-striped table-hover">{% for m in msgs %}';
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td><a href="/detail?sid="{{ m.sid }}">Detail</a></td>';
                    html += '<td>{{ m.date_sent }}</td>';
                    html += '<td>{{ m.from_ }} </td>';
                    html += '<td>{{ m.to }} </td>';
                    html += '<td>{{ m.status }} </td>';
                    html += '</tr>';
                    html += '{% endfor %}</table>';
                    $("#result").html(html);

                    return false;
                //});
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The traceback is:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2016 19:15:05] "GET /logs HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2016 19:15:05] "GET /resources/demos/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
delivered
delivered
127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2016 19:15:20] "POST /custom_log HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1577, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 841, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 867, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I assume that the error arises from the return line. I have experimented with return 'OK', return m.status and this does not produce the desired result either. I want to be bale to pass the result from the Twilio api call back to the ajax function so I can print it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: There seems to be some serious confusion here. Flask templates (with the syntax `{% for m in msgs %}`) are rendered on the server. Javascript runs in the browser, i.e. the client. You can't construct the table like that. Write a loop in javascript which puts the tags together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you're not allowed to return a list. Return `json.dumps(msgs)` and in the javascript parse it as `JSON.parse(response)`. Then you will have a javascript array.

Comment: thank you, seems a good plan. But the error is: TypeError: <twilio.rest.resources.messages.Message object at 0x104760290> is not JSON serializable

Comment: @user1903663 you must extract the info you need and express it purely in terms of simple values (numbers, strings, booleans, and None), lists, and dicts. Javascript and other languages cannot know what a twilio.rest.resources.messages.Message is.

Comment: thank you, and therein lies the problem. In this case, how can I do that?

Comment: `return json.dumps([{'status': m.status, ... <fill in the other keys>} for m in msgs])`.

Comment: With Flask, use `jsonify`, not `json.dumps`. The former will return a response object with the proper content-type.

Comment: thank you Alex, you have given me a great insight from which I can generalize. I am grateful. Thanks too for the note on Flask, dim.

Comment: @dirn thanks from me and OP.